# TPL - task is not awaited

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library

Been using tpl quite a while, and I still have some mysteries to solve :)

When I run this in a console, I would expect all work to be done before it logs "Jobs done":

```
await StartAttachedAsync(() =>
{
  var result = Parallel.For(0, 4, async i =>
  {
    CallContext.LogicalSetData("ContextId", i);
    await Task.Run(async () =>
    {
       await Task.Delay(2000);
       await Task.Run(async () =>
       {
          await Task.Delay(2000);
          Write("Step C done for i " + i);
       });
       Write("Step B done for i " + i);
     });
     Write("Step A done for i " + i);
   });
   Console.WriteLine("For is done: completed = " + result.IsCompleted);
});
Console.WriteLine("Jobs done");


private static async Task StartAttachedAsync(Action action)
{
   await Task.Factory.StartNew(action,
   CancellationToken.None, 
   TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent, 
   TaskScheduler.Default);
}
```

Gives me:

```
For loop is done: completed = True
Jobs done
Step C done for i 0
Step C done for i 2
Step C done for i 3
Step C done for i 1
Step B done for i 1
Step A done for i 1
Step B done for i 0
Step A done for i 0
Step B done for i 3
Step A done for i 3
Step B done for i 2
Step A done for i 2
```

Why is the loop done without awaiting all subtasks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you do a Parallel.For with an async method as body that is not awaited.
So basically what happens is you start some fire and forget tasks in a loop construct.

Better hold a reference to the tasks you create and then do a  `await Task.WhenAll(tasks);`

What's you reason to use `Parallel.For` . Can't you just create a bunch of tasks without it?

In you current code this will do:

```
await StartAttachedAsync(() =>
{
    var tasks = new List<Task>();

    var result = Parallel.For(0, 4, async i =>
    {
        CallContext.LogicalSetData("ContextId", i);
        tasks.Add(Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            await Task.Delay(2000);
            await Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                await Task.Delay(2000);
                Write("Step C done for i " + i);
            });
            Write("Step B done for i " + i);
         }));
         Write("Step A done for i " + i);
    });

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

    Console.WriteLine("For is done: completed = " + result.IsCompleted);
});
```

Comment: Indeed, Parallel.For() normally awaits your lambda, but not if the lambda is async in itself. I'm using WhenAll() now, anyway. Thanks

Comment: @Thomas: `Parallel.For` never `await`s anything; it is strictly incompatible with `async`. If you need to do parallel *and* asynchronous programming (which is fairly rare), use TPL Dataflow.